# Click Event for angularclass for toggle class

Tags: angular5

I have multiple button in my page like below. My problem is when I click on one button all the button color are getting changed.

How can I prevent so that the color of only clicked button is changed?

```
<div class="my_class" (click)="clickEvent()"  
    [ngClass]="status ? 'success' : 'danger'">                
     Some content
</div>
<div class="my_class" (click)="clickEvent()"  
    [ngClass]="status ? 'success' : 'danger'">                
     Some content
</div>
<div class="my_class" (click)="clickEvent()"  
    [ngClass]="status ? 'success' : 'danger'">                
     Some content
</div>

status: boolean = false;
clickEvent(){
    this.status = !this.status;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would to provide a boolean value for each button. I would do something like :

```
<div class="my_class" (click)="status1=!status1"  
    [ngClass]="status1 ? 'success' : 'danger'">                
     Some content
</div>
<div class="my_class" (click)="status2=!status2"  
    [ngClass]="status2 ? 'success' : 'danger'">                
     Some content
</div>
<div class="my_class" (click)="status3=!status3"  
    [ngClass]="status3 ? 'success' : 'danger'">                
     Some content
</div>

status1: boolean = false;
status2: boolean = false;
status3: boolean = false;
```

Pay attention that I didn't use any function. I find this manner quicker and easier if we just want to implement some toggles.